# what is the api endpoint of Workday Create_Job_Requisition Operation? and how to construct connection string in python?

Tags: api, soap, workday-api

what is the api endpoint of Workday Create_Job_Requisition Operation? and how to construct connection string in python? I am new to this so need some expert advices. Basically, I want to connect and post new job posting to Workday.
Thanks in advance.
Tried this link: https://XXXXXXX.workday.com/ccx/service/XXXXXX/Staffing/v39.2
Basic Auth
ISU user
Result: "The requested resource could not be found."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a data source called "Public Web Services" that you can build a custom report off of. The Endpoint field will provide the correct endpoint for the tenant type (IMPL/SALES/PROD), and you will just need to modify the endpoint to include the tenant name between the "//" in the endpoint address.